# Help text not visible

Tags: field

I have added help text for a template field in the `Short Description` field, Japanese version.
When the item is created in the Japanese version, the help text is not seen.

Using Sitecore 9.2

**Template Field:**
[image]

**Item:**
[image]

Answer (score 4):

While not immediately intuitive, this is by design.

The help text follows the *client* language, not the *item* language. So if your user has his or her content editing language settings set to "Japanese", they will be presented with the Japanese help text. For any item language version.

Unfortunately I can find no official link or reference that states this, so you're going to have to take my word for it ;-)

Comment: but is there any workaround. This is only a sinle language site. So the client language is set to Japanese. Creating/Editing is easier that way.